# Android studio's run button does not work

Tags: android

I just shifted to android studio and the run button is not working .
It does nothing when i click at it .
Its is not disabled because it is green not grey and my avd works fine when I  run it through manager, it's just the run command doesn't work; so there is no way i can run my app.
I have tried invalidate caches/ restart it didn't help all. Help.

Comment: Do you have the correct module selected next to the run button?

Comment: Try using the Run in the menu bar and not the icon. If that doesnt work change the Run configurations

Comment: i have done it doesn't work and the configuation is fine.

Comment: and my situation is not the same as the other guys i have checked all th eother questions.So don't mark it as duplicate.